# Как открывать новое окно на месте предыдущего?

Tags: python, tkinter

Нужно при нажатии кнопки чтобы открывалось новое окно, но на месте предыдущего(по тем же координатам, что и было предыбущее). То есть старое окно закрывается, новое открывается, но на том же месте, где закрылось старое.

Comment: Может лучше менять содержимое окна? Например, старое содержимое целиком помещено во фрейм, при нажатии кнопки старый фрем скрывается, создается новый с новым содержимым

Comment: @insolor, тогда придётся код полностью переделывать, а мне лень(

Comment: @DGDays На какие только жертвы не приходится идти разработчикам, чтобы всё выглядело красиво.

Comment: @Jazzis, я это понимаю, но за проект мне всё равно не заплатят(максимум должок за человеком будет), так что мне всё равно

Comment: @DGDays, полностью? Всего лишь нужно добавить в окно фрейм, и всем виджетам прописать его как родительский виджет вместо root.

Comment: @insolor, ну как минимум придется сделать функции изменения размера окна и подмены фрэйма ну и + некоторые заморочки. Если другого варика не предложат, то буду этим заниматься. Там просто 5 окон и все разных размеров

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так это можно сделать. Тут ui -старое окно, root - новое окно

```
def open_window(ui): 
    geo = ui.geometry().split('+')
    x=geo[-2]; y=geo[-1] ui.destroy()
    root=Tk()
    root.geometry(f'300x300+{x}+{y}')
    root.mainloop()
```